# MQTT Retain Messages on Artemis(ActiveMQ) Message Broker

Tags: mqtt, activemq-artemis

I have an issue with retained topics/messages in Artemis Broker. For availability, I want to set up a cluster (hot standby, or something else). To do so in need to switch on persistence. Here lies the problem: MQTT retained topic means the broker keeps the last message per topic and delivers to a new subscribed client. Only the very last message is relevant. This is the part which shall be synchronized in an Artemis cluster between the nodes.

How to configure Artemis, that it persists (and with that sync) only the last message in a topic when it comes with the retained flag. The retained flag comes from the publisher/producer of the message.

There are some config switches, but mainly like the size of the buffer, handling reconnect or drop messages and clients

here is my conifg, hopefully the right part:

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
           xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
<core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">
  <name>0.0.0.0</name>
  <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
  <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
  <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
  <journal-min-files>100</journal-min-files>
  <journal-pool-files>1000</journal-pool-files>
  <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
  <journal-buffer-timeout>444000</journal-buffer-timeout>
  <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
  <disk-scan-period>10000</disk-scan-period>
  <max-disk-usage>95</max-disk-usage>
  <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
  <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
  <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
  <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
  <global-max-size>3221225472</global-max-size>  
  <acceptors>
    <acceptor name="mf1-netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:18884?confirmationWindowSize=-1;clientFailureCheckPeriod=30000;consumerWindowSize=524288;tcpSendBufferSize=2097152;tcpReceiveBufferSize=2097152;protocols=MQTT;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor> 
    <acceptor name="ssl-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:{{ ca_port }}?confirmationWindowSize=-1;clientFailureCheckPeriod=30000;consumerWindowSize=524288;tcpSendBufferSize=2097152;tcpReceiveBufferSize=2097152;sslEnabled=true;enabledProtocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2;needClientAuth=true;keyStorePath={{ keystore_path }};keyStorePassword={{ key_trusstore_pw }};trustStorePath={{ truststore_path }};trustStorePassword={{ trusstore_pw }};protocols=MQTT</acceptor>
    <acceptor name="sync-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:{{ sync_port }}?confirmationWindowSize=-1;clientFailureCheckPeriod=30000;consumerWindowSize=524288;tcpSendBufferSize=2097152;tcpReceiveBufferSize=2097152;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300</acceptor>
  </acceptors>
  <populate-validated-user>true</populate-validated-user>
  <security-settings>
     <security-setting match="#">
        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
        <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
        <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="admin"/>
        <permission type="createAddress" roles="admin"/>
        <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="admin"/>
        <permission type="consume" roles="admin"/>
        <permission type="browse" roles="admin"/>
        <permission type="send" roles="admin"/>            
        <permission type="manage" roles="admin"/>
     </security-setting>
 </security-settings>
 <address-settings>         
     <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting 
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes> -->
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>            
        <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>                  
        <default-consumer-window-size>524288</default-consumer-window-size> 
        <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>
        <auto-delete-queues-message-count>-1</auto-delete-queues-message-count>
        <auto-delete-queues-delay>0</auto-delete-queues-delay>
        <auto-delete-created-queues>true</auto-delete-created-queues>
        <default-purge-on-no-consumers>true</default-purge-on-no-consumers>
        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>  <!-- 10MB -->
        <page-size-bytes>1048576</page-size-bytes> <!-- 1MB -->
        <page-max-cache-size>2</page-max-cache-size> 
     </address-setting>
     <!--default for catch all-->
     <address-setting match="#">
        <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
        <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
        <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting 
        <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes> -->
        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
        <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
        <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
        <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
        <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>            
        <redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>
        <default-last-value-queue>true</default-last-value-queue> 
        <last-value-queue>true</last-value-queue> 
        <default-consumer-window-size>524288</default-consumer-window-size>  
        <auto-delete-addresses>true</auto-delete-addresses>                 
        <auto-delete-queues-message-count>-1</auto-delete-queues-message-count>
        <auto-delete-queues-delay>0</auto-delete-queues-delay>
        <auto-delete-created-queues>true</auto-delete-created-queues>
        <default-purge-on-no-consumers>true</default-purge-on-no-consumers>
        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>  <!-- 10MB -->
        <page-size-bytes>1048576</page-size-bytes> <!-- 1MB -->
        <page-max-cache-size>2</page-max-cache-size> 
     </address-setting>
  </address-settings>     
  <addresses>
     <address name="#">
        <multicast>
            <queue name="." purge-on-no-consumers="true">
                <durable>false</durable>
            </queue>
        </multicast>
     </address>
     <address name="DLQ">
        <anycast>
           <queue name="DLQ" />
        </anycast>
     </address>
     <address name="ExpiryQueue">
        <anycast>
           <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
        </anycast>
     </address>
  </addresses>
</core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Edit the question to show how you have configured Artemis?

Comment: @JustinBertram QOS has absolutely nothing to do with retained messages